# FirebaseAuthentication.net package in Xamarin Forms - get current user UID

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin.forms, firebase-authentication, json.net

In my Xamarin.Forms project, I saw that the FirebaseAuthentication.Net package can be used for the cross-platform project.  How would I get the current user's UID with this?  I have figured out how to get the current user's email by saving the firebase refresh token and using NewtonSoft.JSON, but am not sure how to do this with the id. I want to be able to do this so that I can store the user's data in the database under their uid and retrieve it that way.

Here's what I have so far for getting the email address of the current user:

```
var authProvider = new FirebaseAuthProvider(new FirebaseConfig(WebAPIKey));

var savedfirebaseauth = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth>(Preferences.Get("FirebaseRefreshToken", ""));
var RefreshedContent = await authProvider.RefreshAuthAsync(savedfirebaseauth);
Preferences.Set("FirebaseRefreshToken", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(RefreshedContent));
string UsersEmailToDisplay = savedfirebaseauth.User.Email;
```

What I am storing as "FirebaseRefreshToken" is the following.

```
var auth = await authProvider.CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(Email.Text, Password.Text);
var content = await auth.GetFreshAuthAsync();
var serializedcontent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content);
```

Please let me know if any more clarification of my question is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to get the `UserId` which unique to the Firebase project.

You could try to call its `LocalId` after you sign in.

```
var authProvider = new FirebaseAuthProvider(new FirebaseConfig(""));
var auth = await authProvider.SignInWithOAuthAsync(authType, accessToken);
var uid = auth.User.LocalId;
```

Comment: Yep, I would like to get the user id that is given to each user in authentication.  Also, when I try "FirebaseUser" it says no such thing exists.  When I changed that to "User" it said that it does not contain a definition for UserId

Comment: It's my mistake,you are using FirebaseAuthentication.Net package ,you may try to call user's LocalId.